# How can I select the content in one tag within another tag in XML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

**page** is an object:

```
page= new function(img_data_url, src, pos_x, pos_y)
{
    this.ImgDataURL= img_data_url;
    this.src= src; 
    this.pos_x= pos_x;
    this.pos_y= pos_y;
}
```

And I created a `XML` format to take record its' detail. 
In one edited page, there are several "Stamps", and I have several "Pages".

```
    <Page pid= "0">
<ImgDataURL>asjdfklsadsadfasdf</ImgDataURL>
<Stamp> 
    <src src="../pic/XXX">
    <pos_x>123</pos_x>
    <pos_y>123</pos_y>
    </src>

    <src src="../pic/XXO">
    <pos_x>456</pos_x>
    <pos_y>123</pos_y>
    </src>      
</Stamp>    
</Page>
<Page pid= "1">
<ImgDataURL>asjdfklsadsadfasdf</ImgDataURL>
<Stamp> 
    <src src="../pic/XXX">
    <pos_x>123</pos_x>
    <pos_y>123</pos_y>
    </src>

    <src src="../pic/XXO">
    <pos_x>456</pos_x>
    <pos_y>123</pos_y>
    </src>      
</Stamp>    
</Page>
<Page pid= "2">
<ImgDataURL>asdfsdfasd</ImgDataURL>
<Stamp> 
    <src src="../pic/XXX">
    <pos_x>123</pos_x>
    <pos_y>123</pos_y>
    </src>

    <src src="../pic/XXO">
    <pos_x>456</pos_x>
    <pos_y>123</pos_y>
    </src>      
</Stamp>    
</Page>
```

I want to retrieve the piece of information: `ImgDataURL`,`src of Stamp`,`pos_x of Stamp`, `pos_y of Stamp` in the `XML` file, assigning them back to the object. 

But in the first step, I don't know how to select the **page** by the attribute:"pid" using jQuery. 

`(Or should I have better alternative approaches instead of giving it an id?)`

In the second, how can I do to get all the content within the 
Stamp tag: `src`, `position` and so on...

In the final:
`Any well-designed alternative XML structure is acceptable.`

After all, my purpose is to store the information in the file and get them back to the memory. I hope the manipulation can be as simple as possible.

Comment: is there any reason to use xml  ? json would be much more straightforward

Comment: @mikakun             Actually, json is very strange to me... But if it's very convenient, please post your answer, thanks!

Comment: it's much lighter to carry around & access to json object is also more straightforward & faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you save your json object in .json file (you can use json_encode if you use php on server)

```
pages = {
 '0' : {

      'ImgDataURL' : 'whatever'
      ,Stamp       : {
            src : 'whatefcz'
            ,pos_x : 'cdscsdc'
              }

     },

    '1' : {

     'ImgDataURL' : 'whatever'
      ,Stamp       : {
            src : 'whatefcz'
            ,pos_x : 'cdscsdc'
              }

    },

    ...


  }
```

you can access it directly in your javascript

```
pages['0'].Stamp.src
```

you can load it by including it in a script tag before your scripts or calling the server with getJSON after jquery has loaded

Comment: You cannot access numeric keys like that.. you need to use the `[]` syntax like `pages.['0'].Stamp.src` (*make sure to quote it as well*)

Comment: I use javascript. The html5 new feature. It can access the file system.